# Check file changes on shell script

Tags: shell

i'm currently downloading a file via ssh with shell scripting

the code I have is

ssh $username@$hostname $commands > data.temp

I would like to have a preview of the filesize or something on data.temp

basically I am getting a dbdump with the $commands var.......

is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
watch ls -l data.temp
```

and exit with Ctrl-C.

If you don't have watch: (thanks fge for the correction; watch has 2 second delay by default)

```
while true ; do clear ; ls -l data.temp ; sleep 2 ; done
```

Comment: Suggestions for improvements for solution 2: `while true ; do clear; ls -l data.temp ; sleep 1; done` :)

Comment: yeah... but how can I add that to my script to execute it too..... as you can see I am using that expression above to se start downloading... but I want in the meanwhile do that only with one script! (this is a instalation script :( )

Comment: Make your downloading command run as a background task and check for its status periodically. There are ways, but more details are needed: which OS? Which shell?

Comment: Put this in your script: `ssh ... > data.temp & watch ...` - the ampersand puts the ssh in the background. Or, if ssh is running right now, open a new Terminal. Or type Ctrl-Z to put ssh in background, then: `bg` to keep running ssh. Then use watch.

Comment: As @FelixRabe says, put your ssh command in the background. Then store `$!`, which is the PID of the last background process, into a variable, and check its existence in a while/sleep loop with `pgrep -g $thevar`. When this command exits with non zero, the process has completed. Use `wait` to capture its return code.

Comment: wow! pretty advanced.... could you please write me a sample so I can take a look at?

Comment: still not an option... since the ssh needs the password to login... and it get's all messed up if I use &

Comment: @Killercode - try to use keys instead of passwords. Google for `ssh without password` should be your friend.